# Error al listar datos en Servlets al enviar un ID por metodo POST

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

estoy desarrollando en Jsp usando servlets un sistema de gestor de tareas y necesito mostrar las tareas de cada usuario dependiendo el ID de la persona que ingreso al sistema.
Mi problema es:
Tengo un menú donde al oprimir una etiqueta `<a>` me envía el ID_Usuario del que ingreso al sistema, cuando envía ese ID me muestra las tareas de esa persona, las tareas tienen otro input que tienen el valor del ID_Tarea cuando oprimo este input me debe mostrar las caracteristicas de la tarea seleccionada pero de hay me surguen dos problemas dependiendo una lineas del servlets.
No se si debo hacerlo de esta manera o donde puedo almacenar los ID del usuario evitando que se pierdan su valor.
Mi código es el siguiente.

HOJA DE HTML MENUS.

```
<!-- Datos.getID() es el id del usuario que ingreso  -->

<a class="collapse-item" href="Controlador?menu=MisTareas&accion=ListarTareas&myid=${datos.getID()}"  target="myFrame" >Mis tareas</a>
```

Servlet controlador

```
 if (menu.equals("MisTareas"))
        {  // --- Lista solo las tareas de cierto usuario que ingresar al sistema

            switch (accion)
            {
                case "ListarTareas": // Lista las tareas con foreach de jstl

                    // Aca recibo el Id que me envio al etiqueta <a>
                    int idusuario = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("myid"));

                    // Envio al setter Id_UsuarioDesarrolla este es el usuario que desarrolla la tarea.
                    tareas.setIddesarrolla(idusuario);

                    // Envio al metodo las tareas del id que llego de getParameter
                    List listTareas = daotarea.listTareas(tareas);
                    request.setAttribute("mistareas", listTareas);
                    break;
                //-------------------------------->>>
                case "VerTarea": // Al oprimir input de la tarea muestra las caractersiticas de esa tarea

                    // Recibo el Id de la tarea seleccionada
                    id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idtarea"));

                    // Envio al metodo el ID de la tarea seleccionada
                    tareas = daotarea.vertarea(id);

                    request.setAttribute("tareas", tareas);
                    //=======================================
                    // Mi problema es con la linea siguiente
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=MisTareas&accion=ListarTareas").forward(request, response);
                    //=========== Si dejo la linea  (request.getRequestDispatcher)  me da error al seleccionar una tarea
                    //=========== Si quito esta linea me muestra las caracteristicas pero no vuelve a listar tareas

                    break;

                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Tareasmias.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```